# Nautilus doesn't launch on Ubuntu 16.04 :(nautilus:3653): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

```
$ nautilus
```

Produces the following error output.

```
(nautilus:3653): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed    
(nautilus:3653): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached
(nautilus:3653): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:3653): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:3653): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Nautilus used to work before recent Ubuntu automatic software update. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried the following based on suggestion on another similar thread.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
```

It didn't change anything.

```
$ nautilus -c
```

Produces the following output.

```
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
```

Comment: see any of the recents - http://askubuntu.com/questions/779765/how-can-i-get-the-nautilus-file-manger-to-open http://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error , basically quit nautilus & then restart it.

Comment: Why this happens on rare occasion is apparently unknown. Next time it happens here maybe I can grab some info. (- here I just go nautilus -q & then click on the icon in launcher to restart.